# How do I show multiple plots in the same graph and demarcate specific values through color? I have taken a specific e.g. to illustrate my Q

Tags: r

I need to plot 100 different confidence interval values of a bootstrap distribution by iterating the process 100 times and plotting the confidence interval lines. Then I need to plot 100 line segments corresponding to the confidence intervals and demarcate those lines which fall outside a given value (boldened by drawing a vertical line corresponding to that value) from those that include that given value by coloring. [image: link to the desired graphical output is shown here]

As of now, I could just create the bootstrap for a given repetition only once, I don't know how to repeat the process 100 times and then plot those 100 values. Please help!

**Code that I have written to get the bootstrap distribution once and get the corresponding confidence intervals**:

```
bootstrap1 <-  bowl_sample_1 %>% 
      specify(response = color, success = "red") %>% 
      generate(reps = 1000, type = "bootstrap") %>% 
      calculate(stat = "prop")
  
  percentile1 <- bootstrap1 %>% 
    get_confidence_interval(level = .95, type = "percentile")
  percentile1
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should be rather simple. For ggplot make a data.frame with `start`, `end`, `id` and `colour` indicating whether the value is within or outside the interval. Do the same for a base plot.

Simple reproducible example:

```
set.seet(1000)
start <- runif(100, 0.3, 1)
end <- runif(100, 0, 0.7) 
br <- 0.6
data <- data.frame(id = 1:100, 
                   start = start, 
                   end = end,
                   within = ifelse(br < pmax(start, end) & br > pmin(start, end), 'gray' , 'black'))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(y = id, yend = id, x = start, xend = end, col = within)) + 
  geom_segment() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black" = 'black', "gray" = 'gray'))
```